# Confluence - Use "/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=" for a button

Tags: javascript, html, confluence

I am trying to implement a button or an image that would work the same as the default **Export to PDF** option. This button in turn would be included in a div element. I've found that the code used by Confluence to generate PDF is **/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=#######** where ### indicates the page number.

My current code looks as follows:

```
<style>
div.fixed {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 45px !important;
  right: 0px !important;
  width: 300px;
  text-align:right;
 }
</style>

<div class="fixed">
<input type="button" onclick="location.href=document.referrer; return false;" value="Previous Page" />
<input type="button" onclick="/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=#######;" value="Make PDF" />
 </div>
```

The code works with the first button only. The second button does show but doesn't work even when the pageId is hardcoded. I understand there is a **$content.getIdAsString()** code to get the pageId but so far I haven't had any luck with that either.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

- <strike>have the Export to PDF option implemented on a button and obey all underlying PDF Stylesheet customizations.</strike> I've managed to resolve this. See comment below.
- <strike>IF possible, replace the button with an image e.g. instead of Make PDF button, have a PDF icon. In short, more visual.</strike> Resolved!
- <strike>have the button/image be part of a div element as seen in the code.</strike>  Resolved!

Looking forward to your awesome suggestions.

Comment: I just solved part of the problem: hardcoded the page number and modified the code of the second button as follows: onclick="location.href='/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=171706153'.

This allows to link the Export to PDF action to a button. 

I look forward to receiving your suggestions on the other issues in the original questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the code as follows to resolve all the issues outlined in the original question:

```
<style>
div.fixed {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 45px !important;
  right: 0px !important;
  width: 300px;
  text-align:right;
 }
</style>

<div class="fixed">
<input type="button" onclick="location.href=document.referrer; return false;" value="Previous Page" />
<input type="image" src="image location" onclick="location.href='/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=171706153';">
</div>
```